# How do I split a string by either a whitespace or a comma?

Tags: java

Say I have `foo bar,cat`

Basically I want a list of strings and this should separate by either comma or whitespace.

I can split by comma like so:

```
string.split(",");
```

How can I also include whitespaces here?

Comment: `split("[\\s,]")`

Comment: What if it has both a space and a comma ("foo, bar,cat")? Or two spaces ("foo  bar,cat")? Do you want to see an empty string between the comma and the space, or between each of the two spaces? What about if you have two commas ("foo bar,,cat")?

Answer (score 2):

This will work for any combination of spaces and commas.

- `\\s` is white space which also includes tabs
- `[]` is a character class
- `+` means one or more

```
String[] arr = string.split("[\\s,]+");
```

Using the above, the following strings

```
"foo bar, cat"
"foo    bar    cat"
"foo,,,,   bar  ,  cat"
"foo,bar,cat"
```

Will all return an array containing the three words of `foo`, `bar`, and `cat`

Comment: what happens if the + is missing? Not sure I understood that

Comment: @JohnnyManzel Then its only one space or comma. An alternative regex would be `"\\s|,"` if you cannot have multiple commas in a row

Comment: If the plus is missing, it only checks for a single character of any in the character class.  The + means any combination of those so it could be "cat, dog" or "cat  ,   dog", etc.

Comment: Then, if you have string `ab,,c` you will have 3 fragments instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

You may try a regex split on the pattern `[ ,]+`, which is a character class including one or more spaces or commas:

```java
String input = "foo bar,cat";
String[] parts = input.split("[ ,]+");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

This prints:

```
foo
bar
cat
```